# A telegram bot should send a "quiz" how to do it?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    if call.data == 'start':
        question = "Which city is the capital of France?"
        options = ["Paris", "Berlin", "Madrid", "London"]
        bot.send_poll(call.message.chat.id, question, options)
```

So far, there is such a code. But right now, any answer is the right one. How do I make sure that there is only one correct answer?

It should be borne in mind that I need a "quiz". That is, InlineButtons should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a poll where only one option is correct, you can use the `send_poll` method with the `is_anonymous=False` and `type='quiz'` parameters, along with the `correct_option_id` parameter to specify which option is correct. Since "Paris" is the correct answer and the first option in your options list (with an index of 0), you would set `correct_option_id=0`. This ensures that your poll is recognized as a quiz, and only the option you designate as correct will be treated as such.

Here is how you can modify your code to include these changes:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    if call.data == 'start':
        question = "Which city is the capital of France?"
        options = ["Paris", "Berlin", "Madrid", "London"]
        # Setting correct_option_id to 0 since "Paris" is the first option and the correct answer.
        # Note: The is_anonymous parameter is optional for quizzes, as quizzes are not anonymous by default.
        bot.send_poll(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            question=question,
            options=options,
            is_anonymous=False,
            type='quiz',
            correct_option_id=0
        )
```

In this modified code snippet:

- `is_anonymous=False` ensures that the poll is not anonymous. This is
  optional for quizzes since quiz polls are not anonymous by default.
- `type='quiz'` specifies that the poll is a quiz type, which allows
  for specifying correct answers and automatically calculates scores
  for each participant.
- `correct_option_id=0` indicates that the first option ("Paris") is the
  correct one. The `correct_option_id` is based on the index of the
  correct answer in the options list, starting from 0. By making these
  adjustments, you'll ensure that your poll behaves as a quiz, with
  only "Paris" recognized as the correct answer to the question about
  the capital of France.